# Error while working with Unity. No solution worked.. error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Ports' does not exist in the namespace `System.IO'

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, arduino, serial-port, ports

I have just started working on Arduino-Unity interfacing, but i am facing this error.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO.Ports;
```

I dont think there's some problem in the code. Also I have tried changing API Compatibility Level to .NET 2.0 But that did not worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

> Also I have tried changing API Compatibility Level to .NET 2.0 But
>   that did not worked for me.

**1**. Change API Compatibility Level to .NET 2.0

**2**. Save Unity Project, close Unity then restart Unity.

**3**. Close **Visual Studio** or **MonoDevelop** depending on which one is installed

**4**. Restart **Visual Studio** or **MonoDevelop**

Done! Sometimes, you don't need to do step **2**. Step **1**,**3** and **4** should solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you Sir,,, This problem wasted my 2 days . Thanks a lot ...!!

Comment: This solved my problem to some extent. I need to restart Unity and Visual Studio every time when i make a change in the code... That's how it works now.. Can I make it work perfect?

Comment: @FaceBack You only have to do this once. It should then start working. When you change your code in Visual studio, you go to File->Save All or Ctrl-S then switch back to Unity for it to compile. If that's not working like this then I suggest you uninstall Unity and VS and re-install them. Make sure to install VS from Unity.

Comment: Problem solved...!! I degraded my Unity 5 to Unity 4.6.1